# How can I copy one map into another using std::copy?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, copy

I would like to copy the content of one std::map into another. Can I use `std::copy` for that? Obviously, the following code won't work:

```
int main() {
  typedef std::map<int,double> Map;
  Map m1;
  m1[3] = 0.3;
  m1[5] = 0.5;
  Map m2;
  m2[1] = 0.1;
  std::copy(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin());
  return 0;
}
```

This won't work because `copy` will call `operator*` on `m2.begin()` to "dereference" it and assign a value (all values are of type `std::pair<const int, double>`). Then it will call `operator++` to move to the next space in `m2`. Both of these operations don't work because of the `const` in `const int` and there is no space reserved for any new elements.

Is there any way to make it work with `std::copy`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use GMan's answer --- but the question is, **why** do you want to use `std::copy`? You should use the member function [`std::map<k, v>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead.

```
m2.insert(m1.begin(), m1.end());
```

Comment: Well, if you're gonna avoid using std::copy, why not just use the copy c'tor?  m2 = m1.  edit: Ah, he wants the union of values.

Comment: @Stephen: Because using `insert` preserves the existing contents inside `m2`. Using the copy *assignment* operator destroys the existing contents inside `m2`.

Comment: @Billy: Your answer is clearly the correct answer for the OP, but the answer to why would be "so I can use copy_if", and filter one map during the copy to another.

Comment: @Cheshire `copy_if` != `copy`.

Comment: Stupid question, but why not just do `Map m2 = m1;`?

Answer (score 27):

You need a variant of an [insert iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/):

```
std::copy(m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter(m2, m2.end()) );
```

[`inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/inserter/) is defined in `<iterator>`. It requires a place to insert into (hence the `m2.end()`), and returns an [`insert_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/insert_iterator/).

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but one should prefer member functions to algorithm calls.

Comment: +1 @GMan, +1 @Billy, you guys both got it right. The OP should do what Billy suggests, but GMan in fact answered the question. So, with your powers combined ...

Comment: @WilhelmTell: I AM CAPTAIN PLANET!

Comment: This version works nicely when using the copy_if variant of c++11.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
C++ 98 introduced the '=' operator, which copies the elements from the left into the container. {map& operator= (const map& x);}

C++ 11 added move semantics to move all the elements from the left container {map& operator= (map&& x);}

and initializer list assignment {map& operator= (initializer_list<value_type> il);
}

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator=/