# Accelerated C++ exercise 8-5 solution not clear

Tags: c++, accelerated-c++

I am stuck at solving Accelerated C++ exercise 8-5 and I don't want to miss a single exercise in this book.

Accelerated C++ Exercise 8-5 is as follows:

> Reimplement the `gen_sentence` and `xref` functions from Chapter 7 to use
>   output iterators rather than putting their entire output in one data
>   structure. Test these new versions by writing programs that attach the
>   output iterator directly to the standard output, and by storing the
>   results in `list <string>` and `map<string, vector<int> >`, respectively.

To understand scope of this question and current knowledge in this part of the book - this exercise is part of chapter about generic function templates and iterator usage in templates. Previous exercise was to implement simple versions of `<algorithm>` library functions, such as `equal, find, copy, remove_copy_if` etc.

If I understand correctly, I need to modify `xref` function so it:

- Use output iterator
- Store results in `map<string, vector<int> >`

I tried to pass map iterator as `back_inserter()`, `.begin()`, `.end()` to this function, but was not able to compile it. Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748295/how-can-i-copy-one-map-into-another-using-stdcopy) explains why.

xref function as in Chapter 7:

```
// find all the lines that refer to each word in the input
map<string, vector<int> >
    xref(istream& in,
         vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split)
{
    string line;
    int line_number = 0;
    map<string, vector<int> > ret;

    // read the next line
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        // break the input line into words
        vector<string> words = find_words(line);

        // remember that each word occurs on the current line
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
             it != words.end(); ++it)
            ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Split implementation:

```
vector<string> split(const string& s)
{
    vector<string> ret;
    typedef string::size_type string_size;
    string_size i = 0;

    // invariant: we have processed characters `['original value of `i', `i)'
    while (i != s.size()) {
        // ignore leading blanks
        // invariant: characters in range `['original `i', current `i)' are all spaces
        while (i != s.size() && isspace(s[i]))
            ++i;

        // find end of next word
        string_size j = i;
        // invariant: none of the characters in range `['original `j', current `j)' is a space
        while (j != s.size() && !isspace(s[j]))
            ++j;

        // if we found some nonwhitespace characters
        if (i != j) {
            // copy from `s' starting at `i' and taking `j' `\-' `i' chars
            ret.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
            i = j;
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

Please help to understand what am i missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found more details on the exercise, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608092/accelerated-c-exercise-8-5-wording-help:

> ```
> template <class Out> 
> void gen_sentence( const Grammar& g, string s, Out& out )
> ```
>
> **USAGE:**
>
> ```
> std::ostream_iterator<string> out_str (std::cout, " ");
> gen_sentence(   g, "<sentence>", out_str   );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> template <class Out, class In> 
> void xref(   In& in, Out& out, vector<string> find_words( const string& ) = split   )
> ```
>
> **USAGE:**
>
> ```
> std::ostream_iterator<string> out_str (std::cout, " "); 
> xref(   cin, out_str, find_url   ) ;
> ```

Frankly, I have to come to the conclusion that that question is ill-posed, specifically where they specified the new interface for `xref`: xref should result in a map. However, using output iterators would imply using `std::inserter(map, map.end())` in this case. While you can write a compiling version of the code, this will not do what you expect since `map::insert` will simply ignore any insertions with duplicated keys.

If the goal of xref is only to link the words to the line number of their *first appearance* this would still be ok, but I have a feeling that the author of the exercise simply missed this subtler point :)

Here is the code anyways (note that I invented a silly implementation for `split`, because it was both missing and required):

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}

// find all the lines that refer to each word in the input
template <typename OutIt>
OutIt xref(std::istream& in,
        OutIt out,
        std::vector<std::string> find_words(const std::string&) = split)
{
    std::string line;
    int line_number = 0;

    // read the next line
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        // break the input line into words
        std::vector<std::string> words = find_words(line);

        // remember that each word occurs on the current line
        for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
             it != words.end(); ++it)
            *out++ = std::make_pair(*it, line_number);
    }

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, int> index;

    std::ifstream file("/tmp/test.cpp");
    xref(file, std::inserter(index, index.end()));

#if __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
    for(auto& entry: index)
        std::cout << entry.first << " first found on line " << entry.second << std::endl;
#else
    for(std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it = index.begin();
        it != index.end();
        ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " first found on line " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry about not posting `split` implementation. I'll add it to my question. The situation is that I am not familiar with `make_pair` function. A little search discovered that `make_pair` is only mentioned in library summary at the end of the book, so it's still not clear for me what author tried to tech with this exercise.

Comment: make_pair is a template method. If you have some type like: `std::pair<std::string, int>` it's easier to use: `make_pair("hello", 5);` rather than: `std::pair<std::string, int>("hello", int)` it kind of infers what kind of pair you want to make.

Comment: Two more notes. 1) The xref function originally returned `map<string, vector<int> >` containing string and vector of int with each line word occurred on. (attached code in the answer prints only line word was first found on) 2) I should be able to attach the output iterator directly to the standard output. Either I don't know how to do it or solution should be implemented differrently?

Comment: @user1104456: you should only expect to attach an output iterator to stdout for the call to `gen_sentence`. I assumed you weren't interested in that part because **(a)** it was missing completely from your question **(b)** it is trivial with regards to the output iterator (it is the _map_ that poses the challenge, in my view)