# constness issue when inserting into an std::map

Tags: c++, constants, stdmap, visual-c++-2012

I'm experiencing an constness issue when attempting to insert a pair into a map.  The compiler error is:

```
              c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2089) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::operator =(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const Assets::AssetId,
1>              _Ty2=std::shared_ptr<Assets::Material>
1>          ]
1>          c:\fusionengine\meshgl.cpp(85) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const Assets::AssetId,
1>              _Ty2=std::shared_ptr<Assets::Material>
1>          ]
```

The line causing the error is:

```
m_materials.insert( MaterialsMap::value_type(pMaterial->AssetId(), pMaterial) );
```

The m_materials map is declared as follows:

```
typedef std::map< Assets::AssetId, std::shared_ptr<Material> > MaterialsMap;    
typedef std::pair< Assets::AssetId, std::shared_ptr<Material> > MtlPair;

MaterialsMap  m_materials;
```

Error   1   error C2166: l-value specifies const object c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility  114

Can anyone explain how I resolve this issue?

Comment: The standard way to insert data into `std::map` is using `std::make_pair`, not `std::map::value_type`.

Comment: @KirilKirov: `value_type` is just as standard. It is of type `pair<cosnt Key, Mapped>`, which should work fine. AFAIK the implementation is not permitted to call `operator=`, only copy constructors are involved here. So my guess: dinkumware bug.

Comment: @ybungalobill - sure, I'm not saying, that this is the problem, that's why I added it as a comment. My point was, that in my experience, I've never seen anyone to use `map::value_type`. But I don't have that much experience, so I may be wrong. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I sometimes prefer to use `value_type` because then I don't need to include additional headers. (Is it `<utility>` where `make_pair` is defined?)

Comment: @ybungalobill - I see. I never include `<utility>`, when I have included `<map>`, I think it's included there or something. The only time, I include `<utility>` is when I use `std::pair` not with `std::map`.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I know. MSVC library heavily pollutes the namespace, so when including anything you get much other junk too. But including map is not required to bring `make_pair` into the scope. It is actually really hard to factor the library so that it won't do such things. And I do not know to what degree other implementations do that...

Comment: @KirilKirov The type required by `std::map::insert` is `std::map::value_type`.  That's what I use; I don't think I've every used `std::make_pair`.

Comment: Okay, I agree. (with @JamesKanze and @ybungalobill)

Comment: @KirilKirov: Another comment regarding the selection of `value_type` and `make_pair`. In C++03 (or C++11 if the type does not have an efficient move constructor), the type of `make_pair` is determined by the arguments, not the target and that can block copy elision: `std::map<std::string,int> m; m.insert(std::make_pair(non_const_long_str),1);` --> `make_pair` will create a `std::pair<std::string,int>` and perform one copy, `insert` requires a `std::pair<const std::string,int>` and will require a second copy. Finally the map will do a third copy into the node. You can avoid one of the copies.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I've tried std::make_pair, value_type and explicitly declaring std::pair<uint, std::shared_ptr<Mtl>>.  It all fails with exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code [compiles fine with GCC](http://ideone.com/HkF0YC):

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

typedef int AssetId;
struct Material {
    int _id;
    Material(int id) : _id(id) {}
    int AssetId() const { return _id; }
};
typedef std::map< AssetId, std::shared_ptr<Material> > MaterialsMap;    

MaterialsMap  m_materials;

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Material> pMaterial(new Material(42));
    m_materials.insert( MaterialsMap::value_type(pMaterial->AssetId(), pMaterial) );
}
```

Either your example is incomplete or wrong, or this is a bug in the implementation of the standard library of MSVC2012. It *shall not* call `operator=` in the above code.

Comment: Or he's misquoted something, or this is a knock-on from a problem elsewhere.  I regularly insert `std::map::value_type` into a map, and I can't remember ever having a problem with it, including with Microsoft compilers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: 1) the OP uses MSVC2012, which quite new and I have not even tried yet. 2) this is not "microsoft compiler" but a "dinkumware library". 3) there were quite much degradations. E.g. MSVC2010 managed to break `std::pair`.

Comment: Dinkumware is (or at least was) the supplier of the library to Microsoft, but the library is part of the compiler, and when it comes with the Microsoft compiler, it's the Microsoft library, regardless of who wrote it.  And I don't have access to MSVC2012, but I can image that all of the changes necessary to add support for rvalue references would introduce a few bugs.  (And since my impression is that Microsoft doesn't test the produces they deliver...)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Excuse me, but the library is definitely *not* a part of the compiler. You can change the default include paths and disable linking with default libraries thus using another library implementation with *the same* compiler. And this is not hypothetical. I remember seeing working 3rd party implementations for writing real C++ in kernel mode.

Comment: The library is defined by the C++ standard, as part of the language; the very first sentence in the standard says that it defines the language.  When I buy or install a compiler, the library comes with it.  And you can do a lot of things with options which mean that you no longer have a C++ compiler.

Comment: @JamesKanze: the C++ standard defines "the language", which is implemented by "an implementation". A typical implementation is made of a compiler, a linker, a library, the underlining system and machine, etc... The standard does not define the actual components or the options of your compiler. By changing any of these components you get a different "implementation", but as long as the whole conglomerate conforms to the standard it *is* an implementation of "The C++ Language". So either you come and say from the perspective of a language lawyer that "the implementation used by OP is not

Comment: standard conforming", or come down to the real world and distinguish the components of this whole system, recognizing that these components, although usually distributed on the same physical medium, actually are independent to some degree and can be used to assemble other "implementations". Anyway the library is not part of the MS compiler, it is only distributed with it. MSVC compiler is `cl.exe` and the accompanying DLLs. The library is a set of headers and libs which reside in a different directory.

Comment: The components of the system depend on how the system is implemented.  Using the traditional meaning for "compiler", for example, neither `g++` nor `cl.exe` are compilers.  (They're both driver programs, which may invoke the compiler, the linker, or other programs.)  Using the more general meaning, which is what the standard does (and this meaning seems to be wide spread today): both are compilers, and the standard library is part of them (i.e. it comes with them, I don't have to specify it separately as a library, etc.).

Comment: And whether the standard library headers reside in a separate directory or not, or even if they exist as files, is a property of the implementation.  An implementation can organize the directories behind the scenes however it pleases.

Answer (score 3):

I tore my hair out over this issue, I probably spent on and off a week on it.  Luckily it wasn't critical to the project roadmap, so it didn't prevent from continuing.

The issue was not compiler related, although the error reporting could do with enhancement, although I realise that that's always been an issue with template (and STL) code.

So I had an std::copy in my operator= overload to copy the contents of one map to another.  Little did I know that this is a no-no.

I finally found this out by building the entire class up again, line by line and function by function, in order to isolate the problem area.

Then by examining the problem area and googling, stackoverflow came to the rescue with this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748295/how-can-i-copy-one-map-into-another-using-stdcopy).

While the following statement is illegal, it is not highlighted as an error in the VS2012 IDE, nor does the compiler identify it as a problem statement.

```
std::copy( map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin() );
```

As the previously highlighted SO answer states, the correct way to do this is with an insert statement:

```
map2.insert( map1.begin(), map1.end() );
```

I hope this helps someone out there :)