# Copy map of unique_ptr using map::insert

Tags: c++, stdmap

Is there a possibility to deep-copy a `std::map` of `std::unique_ptr` to another one using [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) or [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

I have the following:

```
class MyObject {}

std::map<int32_t, std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> entries1;

// Populate entries1
// ...

std::map<int32_t, std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> entries2;

entries2.insert(entries1.begin(), entries1.end());
```

Obviously, using a simple insert won't work, because `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable:

> attempting to reference a deleted function

In this answer [How can I copy one map into another using std::copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748295/how-can-i-copy-one-map-into-another-using-stdcopy/2748303#2748303), a custom inserter is sugested together with `std::copy`, but I really don't know how to use it in my context.

Is the manual implementation (iterating and copying each object in a loop) the only solution? E.g.:

```
for (const auto &entry : entries1)
{
    entries2.insert({ entry.first, std::make_unique<MyObject>(*entry.second) });
}
```

Comment: You could use a smart pointer type that does a deep copy upon its own copy, and I think boost has some kind of "pointer map" data structure.

Comment: Use `entries2.emplace_hint(entries2.end(), entry.first, std::make_unique<ObjectInfo>(*entry.second));`, and it's not so bad.

Comment: But if the mapped type is copyable, why use unique pointers at all?

Comment: @Kerrek, wow, `emplace_hint` really improves the performance significantly. For 1.000.000 objects, the copy now takes ~450ms instead of ~790ms

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe they will be taken out of the map later and copying is expensive?

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe he want to hold a serious of polymorphic object?

Comment: @ChenOT: In that case copying those objects isn't as easy as the code makes it look.

Comment: `std::copy` just does the copy assignment via iterators like `*d_iter++ = *s_iter++`. Try to wrap your object to override `operator=` behavior?

Comment: You're not going to get anything clearer or more maintainable than your "manual implementation" (hopefully with Kerrek's optimisation), but if you're determined to avoid that you could use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda calling `make_unique`....