# VS 2012 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found doing std::copy of map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I can't find a way to make compile the following simple stl code in VS 2012:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>

...
class SomeClass;
SomeClass a;
std::map<std::string, SomeClass> x;
x["a"] = a;
std::map<std::string, SomeClass> y;
std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::inserter(y, y.end()));
```

I always get the VS compiler error:

```
xutility(2089): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

**UPDATE**

I'm really sorry! I managed to isolate the offending code and this was it. It basically is a type contravariance issue of the smart pointer `shared_ptr` because it can't copy `anAImplPtr = anAPtr` even when `anAPtr` is actually pointing to a wrapper of an `AImpl` instance:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
    #include <boost/thread.hpp>

class A
{       
  public:
    virtual ~A() { } 
};

class AImpl : public A {
  public:
    virtual ~AImpl() { } 
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<AImpl> AImplPtr;

static void test() 
{
  std::map<std::string, APtr> x;
  APtr a(new AImpl());
  x["a"] = a;
  std::map<std::string, AImplPtr> y;
  std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::inserter(y, y.end()));
}
```

Comment: It works on MSVC2015, what happens if you include `#include <iterator>` ?

Comment: According to [an answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748295/how-can-i-copy-one-map-into-another-using-stdcopy) that should work.

Comment: Sorry yes this example works but it seems that the issue is in the actual SomeClass

Comment: Then please post a [mcve]

Comment: Right, working on it ... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Don't use</s> Avoid using `std::copy` with `std::map`, <s>way too complex to make it work</s> it make error messages cryptic with old VS compilers. Alternative:

```
y.insert(x.begin(), x.end());
```

If it fails, you should get a more explicit error message.

Comment: Good advice but not really an answer.  The OP needs to provide a mcve before we can really answer this.

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right, I'm waiting on this mcve to update my answer.